# Rails loses change tracking when calling instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activemodel

When changing a model's attributes in the controller's update, I want to generate a history of changes that are about to be made. For that, I've created a method `generate_history` to access from the instance.

The class:

```
class Assist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: status

    def generate_history
        #Also tried without self

        p 'Testing round two'
        p 'Status' + self.status.id.to_s
        p 'Modified: ' + self.status.id_changed?.to_s
        p 'Old value ' + self.status.id_was.to_s

        #do something something dark side
    end

end
```

The issue is within that method, the `ActiveModel::Dirty` isn't aware of the changes that have been made, although the `self.status_id`'s value is the new one.

Meanwhile in the controller:

```
def update

    ...

    @assist.assign_attributes(assist_params)

    p 'Testing round one'
    p 'Status' + @assist.status_id.to_s
    p 'Modified: ' + @assist.status_id_changed?.to_s
    p 'Old value ' + @assist.status_id_was.to_s

    p 'Generating history'

    @assist.generate_history

    p 'Testing round three'
    p 'Status' + @assist.status_id.to_s
    p 'Modified: ' + @assist.status_id_changed?.to_s
    p 'Old value ' + @assist.status_id_was.to_s
end
```

At first I was suspicious of `assign_attributes` that somehow interfered with `ActiveModel::Dirty` but I've realized that `ActiveModel::Dirty` works in the controller, where the values are being modified, but not when I'm calling `generate_history`.

Am I doing something wrong from within the instance method or its the way `ActiveModel::Dirty` works?

Example of output:

```
Testing round one
Status 1
Modified: true
Old value 2

Generating history
Testing round two
Status 1
Modified: false
Old value 1

Testing round three
Status 1
Modified: true
Old value 2
```

Comment: Have you tried looking for the 'dirtiness' through the `status` attribute?  Instead of `.status_id`, try `.status.id` and `.status_changed?`.  It might work...

Comment: @mr-rogers `.status.changed?` reports false within the method

Comment: sad.  well, worth a try.

Comment: @mr-rogers Actually, you are right. I had within the generate_history method the .status.id and .status.id.changed? (which reported no modificaitons) while I was testing the output of .status_id.changed? in the controller. Can you put that as answer?

Comment: Sure.  glad that helped.  Let me know if the answer posted matches what you got working.  I was spitballing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the `status_id` is not an attribute that is fully tracked by `ActiveRecord::Dirty`.  Instead of looking at `status_id`, i think you should look at `status`.  Something like:

```
class Assist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: status
    def generate_history
        p 'Testing round two'
        p 'Status' + status_id.to_s
        p 'Modified: ' + status_id_changed?.to_s
        p 'Old value ' + status_id_was.to_s

        #do something something dark side
    end
end
```

Then your controller code is right.

And because you're not assigning `status` but only asking about it, you probably don't need the `self.`

Comment: Actually, is the other way around. status_id was the actual field being updated as it came from the params

Comment: Got it.  I just tried it on one of my projects and saw the difference.  The dots and underscores are slippery suckers.